# How to extract dates from apply.monthly function

Tags: r, xts

If I have a set of daily data, I want to get the minimum value for each month, and the date on which that value occurred. If I use the `apply.monthly` function, it gives me the minimum value, but the corresponding date is the end of every month, not the date when it actual occurred. How can I get the correct date?

```
library(xts)
#create sample data
dates<-seq(from=as.Date("1970-01-01"),to=as.Date("1970-12-31"),by=1)
x<-sample(1:365,365)
ts<-xts(x,dates)

#apply function
monthly.mins<-apply.monthly(ts,min)
monthly.mins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply.monthly` uses `period.apply`, and *always* indexes at the endpoint of each period.  If you want different behavior, you need to use more general functions.

In this case, you can use the `lapply(split(), ...)` idiom with a custom function:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(ts,"months"), function(x) x[which.min(x)]))
```